# Xpath returns empty array - lxml

Tags: python, web-scraping, xpath, lxml

I'm trying to write a program that scrapes https://www.tcgplayer.com/ to get a list of Pokemon TCG prices based on a specified list

```
from lxml import etree, html
import requests
import string

def clean_text(element):
    all_text = element.text_content()
    cleaned = ' '.join(all_text.split())
    return cleaned


page = requests.get("http://www.tcgplayer.com/product/231462/pokemon-first-partner-pack-pikachu?xid=pi731833d1-f2cc-4043-9551-4ca08506b43a&page=1&Language=English")

tree = html.fromstring(page.content)

price = tree.xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div/div/section[2]/section/div/div[2]/section[3]/div/section[1]/ul/li[1]/span[2]")

print(price)
```

However, when I am running this code the output ends up just being an empty list "[]"

I have tried using selenium and the browser function that it has, however I would like it to not need to open a browser for 100+ cards to get the price data. I have tested this code on another website url and xpath (https://www.pricecharting.com/game/pokemon-promo/jolteon-v-swsh183, /html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/table/tbody[1]/tr[1]/td[4]/span[1]) - so I wonder if it is just how https://www.tcgplayer.com/ is built.

The expected return value is around $5

Comment: Looks like that page is mostly just javascript, and `requests` does not understand javascript.

Comment: When you test the XPath on a site, you probably do this in the Developer Console in the browser, after the page has loaded. At that point in time, any JavaScript will have already executed and completed and the page may have been updated or even been constructed from scratch by it. When using `requests`, it just loads the basic page and no scripts get executed - you'll need something that can execute JavaScript to get the same result, like `selenium`.

Comment: Ah, okay. That makes sense as to why it was working with selenium but not with just lxml. Thanks for the indepth explanation @Grismar

Comment: You're welcome - there's a couple of gotchas like this in web scraping, I [collected a bunch in a single answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73808177/beautifulsoup-scraping-returns-no-data)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question answered above by @Grismar:

> When you test the XPath on a site, you probably do this in the Developer Console in the browser, after the page has loaded. At that point in time, any JavaScript will have already executed and completed and the page may have been updated or even been constructed from scratch by it. When using `requests`, it just loads the basic page and no scripts get executed - you'll need something that can execute JavaScript to get the same result, like `selenium`

[BeautifulSoup scraping returns no data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73808177/beautifulsoup-scraping-returns-no-data)